# Is it necessary to add custom error handling in Production for Asp.net Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

I have an Asp.net Core 6 Web Api.

I want to prevent the app from exposing sensitive information in Production when an unhandled exception occurs.

Firstly, I decided to test the default behaviour for Production just to see how much data is exposed.

I adjusted the environment to Production and threw an exception in one of the Controller actions:

```
[HttpGet("own-data")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecastViewModel> Get()
{
    
    throw new Exception();

    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecastViewModel
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}


 "FirstProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7001;http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
```

In production the content length is 0.

This makes me think that Asp.Net Core 6 has built-in mechanisms to prevent sensitive information from leaking in Production.

So I am wondering - in such a case - is it necessary to add custom exception filtering and handling myself?

I see that there is detailed [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler) how to add custom exception handling to asp.net core for production. But is it necessary to add it?

Comment: In production you would like to send some information back to the client: e.g., friendly error message, error status code and/or a traceId/correlationId which your clients can provide back to you to investigate why they get errors.
Many design patterns use this with exception, e,g, your code may throw a custom exception and then your exception handler will convert it to status code + error message.

Comment: Answer to this question would be opinion and suggestions only. so at the end it is all about requirements. if you want your API consumers to know more about failure of API call, you can choose to write a custom exception handling middleware or leave it as it is in case you want to always return common error.